# Custom event handling for KafkaAdminClient

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

My goal is to do something when the broker is down, but couldn't manage to do it.

The code is simple:

```
val properties = new Properties()
properties.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092")
val client = AdminClient.create(properties)
//Suppose that the App just runs from here without consuming/producing
```

it starts up, then I manually shutdown kafka.

```
Logs arrives:
2021-06-23T13:51:16,681+02:00 WARN  [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

How to handle this? Basically I just want to invoke a custom method when the broker is down.

- there is nothing I can 'catch'
- And couldn't even find an evenListener in AdminClient/KafkaAdminClient (or I am just looking at the wrong place)

edit: And of course I would like to invoke my custom code too when the broker is back to life

Comment: @RanLupovich "What are you trying to do when the broker is down?"
sending a note about this event to an external system.

Answer (score 0):

You cant issue a command to a server that isn't running... You would need to run a Kafka Java process check on the broker server *itself* that does not use Kafka-related tools (e.g. `jps` or `systemctl` or checking some `/var/run/kafka.pid`)

Comment: "You cant issue a command to a server that isn't running" The server to which I want to send a command in case of broker down is still running. Has nothing to do with kafka.
AdminClient also still running otherwise it won't log 'brokerdown' warnings.

Comment: You said "then [you] manually shutdown kafka", which means that the AdminClient (and all other clients) will disconnect, and there is nothing that you can catch or watch because all Kafka client processes will fail. As answered, you need external process monitoring on the broker itself. You could also set a ZNode watch on `/brokers/ids` if you really wanted immediate feedback

Comment: "because all Kafka client processes will fail" Not at all, they are still running, while constantly logging about the  broker down problem.

Comment: I guess that depends on what framework you use, but I recall that by default a plain `kafka-clients` app will fail to start completely when `Broker may not be available`